# iOS, Swift : Download multiple file serially and showing single progress bar for all file as a one progress

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading the zip file using the Alamofire in my ios(swift4) application. I am able to download the file serially using Alamofire.
But I also want to show the one progress bar for the all the downloaded files. Means If I have 4 zip files and when all the file is downloaded then the progress should be 100%.

Till I have tried below code, which gives a progress value for each of the url and progress is shown as one file downloaded showing progress as 100% then again it start from 0 for second url and when second url is downloaded then progress is shown 100% complete.

Please guide me for this. I want to get progress value as 100% when all the files are downloaded using Alamofire.

Can it be possible with Alamofire?

CODE:

```
func serialZipFileDownload(downloadPath: String){
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let name = self.offlineDownloadFileName?[urlCount]
    let currentVideoURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(name ?? "Default.zip")
    let str = downloadPath
    let urlString = str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    let url = URL(string: urlString ?? "")

if super.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let headers = ["Accept-Encoding" : ""]

    manager.request(url ?? "", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).downloadProgress { (progress) in
        print(progress.fractionCompleted)

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.progressDownload.setProgress((Float(progress.fractionCompleted)), animated: true)
            let per = round((Float(progress.fractionCompleted)) * 100)
            self.lblDownloadPercent.text = "\(Int(per))%"
        }
    }.responseData { (response) in
        switch (response.result){
        case .success(_) :
            print(response)
            print(response.result.value!)
            print(response.result.description)

            if let data = response.result.value {
                do {
                    try data.write(to: currentVideoURL)
                    self.showToast(message: "File downloaded successfully")
                }
                catch {
                    print("Something went wrong!")
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error) :
            print(response)
            if error._code == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    super.showPopup(title: msgStruct.networkTitle, message: msgStruct.noInternet)
                }
            }
            else if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    super.showPopup(title: msgStruct.networkTitle, message: msgStruct.noInternet)
                }
            }
            else if error._code == NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream {
                print("error",error.localizedDescription)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
else{
    super.showPopup(title: msgStruct.networkTitle, message: msgStruct.noInternet)
}
```

Comment: One suggestion is to divide fractionCompleted by 4 and do not reset the progress bar between each file. It will not be exactly true if file sizes vary a lot but it is an easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
Maintain a global variable - **tatalPercentage** some other swift class.

```
  static let tatalPercentage = 0
```

---

```
tatalPercentage = tatalPercentage + Int(per/4)
self.lblDownloadPercent.text = "\(tatalPercentage) %"
```